# Inserting a table into multiple PDF pages with columnText

Tags: itext

I am trying to insert a table into a PDF template.  It is successful when the table fits on the page.  However, if it is too big then we lose data.  I basically just want it to paste what is left of the ColumnText to a next page which looks like page # 5.

Here is my current code, it is creating a blank white page in front of page #4 and it is writing the remaining ColumnText data over where it already pasted the first time.

```
PdfImportedPage templatePage = stamper.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, 5);

int pageNum = 5;

while (true)
{
      ct.SetSimpleColumn(-75, 50, PageSize.A4.Height + 25, PageSize.A4.Width - 200);
      if (!ColumnText.HasMoreText(ct.Go()))
            break;
      pageNum++;
      stamper.InsertPage(pageNum, new Rectangle(792f, 612f));
      stamper.GetOverContent(pageNum).AddTemplate(templatePage, 0, 0);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a small code sample named [AddLongTable](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/AddLongTable) that you can use to complete your code. The reason why all the content is added to the same page is simple. You forgot this line:

```
ct.setCanvas(stamper.getOverContent(pageNum));
```

Note that my example is written in Java, but I'm sure you'll know how to adapt it to C#. If you post your fix in a comment, I'll update my answer, adding the C# version of the solution.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but for some reason I can't find an equivalent for setCanvas in C#.  Any ideas?

Comment: What about `ct.Canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(pagenum);`

Comment: Do you know what the best way to go about retrieving the template off of a landscaped page?  Now that my table is posting correctly, my template isn't getting added correctly.  It basically just needs a rotate of 90.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you. As for rotating templates: in Java, you can ask a page for its rotation with the `getRotation()` method, so it's either `templatePage.Rotation` or `templatePage.GetRotation()` that you need to determine the rotation. You need a different `AddTemplate()` method to apply the rotation or to wrap the page inside an `Image` and apply the rotation to that image.